# How to await table creation/make it persist in Jest Unit Test with async-await?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

I have 2 tables, `producers` and `contacts`. To add information into the `contacts` table I must first add information to the `producers` table. This is my unit test:

```
'use strict'

const Contacts = require('../modules/contacts.js')
const Producers = require('../modules/producers.js')


describe ('Add contact information()' , () => {

    test('Add contacts', async done => {
        expect.assertions(6)
        const producer = await new Producers()
        await producer.addProducer('James')
        const contact = await new Contacts()
        await contact.addContacts('James', 'www.johnwick.com', 'john@johnwick.com', '07724890765', '24, John Wick Street, London')
        const data = await contact.getAll()
        await expect (data.length).toBe(1)
        expect (data[0].ProducerID).toBe(1)
        expect (data[0].ProducerWebsite).toBe('www.johnwick.com')
        expect (data[0].ProducerEmail).toBe('john@johnwick.com')
        expect (data[0].ProducerNumber).toBe('07724890765')
        expect (data[0].ProducerAddress).toBe('24, John Wick Street, London')
        done()
    })

})
```

The problem is that when the `producers` table gets created when using the `addProducer` function it does not persist for the `addContacts` function to use it. How do I solve that? Here's the feedback from the Jest Unit Test:

```
 FAIL  unit tests/contacts.spec.js
  Add contact information()
    × Add contacts (80ms)

  ● Add contact information() › Add contacts

    SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: producers



  console.log modules/producers.js:22
    Add Producer James

  console.log modules/producers.js:32
    Producer successfuly added.

  console.log modules/producers.js:67
    [ { ProducerID: 1, ProducerName: 'James' } ]
```

As you can see, it does create it, but only after the error is thrown??

Here's the code for the producers table being made:

```
'use strict'

const sqlite = require('sqlite-async')

module.exports = class Producers {


    //Create Database Table if it doesn't exist
    constructor(dbName = ':memory:') {
        return (async() => {
            this.db = await sqlite.open(dbName)
            const sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS producers(ProducerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, ProducerName TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)'
            await this.db.run(sql)
            return this
        })()
    }

    //Add function to add producers to database if not existing or add product types if producer exists. 
    async addProducer(name) {

        console.log('Add Producer', name)
        
        //Check if there are any Producers with the same name
        let sql = `SELECT * FROM producers WHERE ProducerName="${name}"`
        const data = await this.db.all(sql)
        
        //If producer doesn't exist add to database
        if(data.length === 0) {
            sql = `INSERT INTO producers (ProducerName) VALUES("${name}")`
            await this.db.run(sql)
            console.log('Producer successfuly added.')
        }
        
        //Else return error saying producer exists
        else {
            console.log('Producer already exists.')
            throw new Error ('Producer already exists.')
        }
    }
```

And here's the code for the contacts table being made:

```
'use strict'

const sqlite = require('sqlite-async')

module.exports = class Contacts {


    //Create Database Table if it doesn't exist
    constructor(dbName = ':memory:') {
        return (async() => {
            this.db = await sqlite.open(dbName)
            const sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(ProducerID INTEGER, ProducerWebsite TEXT, ProducerEmail TEXT, ProducerNumber INTEGER, ProducerAddress TEXT)'
            await this.db.run(sql)
            return this
        })()
    }

    async addContacts (ProducerName, ProducerWebsite, ProducerEmail, ProducerNumber, ProducerAddress){
        // if(isNaN(Number.parseInt(ProducerNumber))) throw new Error('The Producer Number cannot contain letters')
        let sql = `INSERT INTO contacts (ProducerID, ProducerWebsite, ProducerEmail, ProducerNumber, ProducerAddress) VALUES (
            (SELECT ProducerID FROM producers WHERE ProducerName="${ProducerName}"), 
            "${ProducerWebsite}", "${ProducerEmail}", "${ProducerNumber}", "${ProducerAddress}")`
        await this.db.run(sql)
    }
```

Comment: You might have to check if the table gets created as your async function gets resolved? Or check where does the delay come from as well?

Comment: remove async from constructors and use async class methods to do your db init

Answer (score 0):

I think each class is creating it's own in-memory database independent from the other.

According to https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

> Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two
> database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two
> independent in-memory databases.

So either create the DB at a single place and reuse the instance or use one of the methods in the link to share the in-memory database between the entities.

Comment: async constructors :)

Comment: @MartinChaov that was my first guess, but apparently they do work. Here is an example that work perfectly fine in Chrome. https://pastebin.com/9jV6gzLn
So it should be the memory databases...